# Magnetism and potential energy - Energy Harvesting

Tags: magnetic-fields, potential-energy

I know and understand that a generator comprised of solely permanent magnets can not work. From my understanding, it basically has to do with the fact that when you pull magnets appart or push them together you are building potential energy and the potential energy built by pulling magnets appart or pushing together is going to be equal to the potential energy released by allowing them to come back togehter or fly appart. There's actually this awesome youtube channel (https://www.youtube.com/@yWild) that has great visualisations as to why these setups can not work, but also why standard assumptions about "magnetic shielding" aslo don't work in these "generators."

All in all, pretty satisfied with all the explanations and I'm in the camp that this kind of generator can not work.

Any ways, I've been thinking about potential energy manipulations, like what happens with heat pumps, and it got me thinking: It's significantly easier to pull magnets appart when the direction of separation is radial vs when the direction of pull is axial.

So theoretically. If I have the to magnets face-to-face, but not touching, and their rotation is locked and I pull them appart, I should have to fight a "small" level of force in order to create X distance of separation. If I instead, pull them axially, I will have to fight a relatively "large" level of force in order to pull them appart.

Fair enough, but the, work is equal to force * distance. So if I lock the rotation of the magnets, and I separate them x centimeters, then I unlock the rotation by pulling a lynch pin and allow them to pull together axially. That would magnify the potential energy available at that separation distance. Then I should spend "W = F_radial * distance" and I should recieve back "W = F_axial * distance" shouldn't I?

Then I though, If I had the magnets on locking spinners on a stator and rotor arrangement, then when the rotor magnet moves away from the stator magnet I'm fighting the radial attractive forces and also throwing off the polar alignment of the rotor magnet and stator magnets, causing the force of attraction fall off even faster. Then at the half-way point between stator magnets, all the stator magnets and rotor magnets could be unlocked, they'll spin to align poles and the potential energy at that point will be magnified, just like in the pulling system. As a user, you don't spend energy spinning the magnets, you just pull a latch/pin and let a spring push it back when the magnets are close together and axially aligned again.

While normally, I understand why a set-up using permanent magnets or trying to move "shield" (conductors full of eddy currents) into place can not work, this I do not understand why it wouldn't work. This concept seems more like a clever use of the difference in potential energies available from the differing alignments of magnets at the same position.

Is there a reason why pulling them appart in a "weak" direction then extracting potential energy from the "strong" direction wouldn't work?

Comment: The work difference will be the work required to reorient the magnets when they are far apart to complete the cycle. This is assuming the quasi static limit. If you do it fast enough, you’ll need to worry about radiation as well.

Comment: Right, so I won't ever manually rotate them, only ever set and release the lunch pin, their rotation will be a function of their position and the state of the lynch pin. But otherwise the logic makes sense? That w_axial must be more than w_radial since F_axial is larger than f_radial?

Comment: lynch pin, not lunch pin lol... One way or another, I'm going to find out......The miracles of 3d printing!

Comment: I'm printing parts to do the experiment as we speak, interested in the results? Should I pm you?

Comment: Yes apart from that the two works are different. That would be interesting. Perhaps you could include your results by answering your question for future viewers.

Comment: Sure thing, it'll be a bit longer though, I only had 2 disc magents and I discovered, that the effect mostly works, but I need to buy some more magnets because the pole-to-pole thickness need to be >= the magnets width to keep the polar alignment through the whole return stroke.

It's so cool, the magnets repel after 2 radii of latteral displacement, then I click the linch pins and they fly back together.

Comment: I'll share the 3d print files with any one who wants them too, I'm not looking to be called a liar

Answer (score 0):

I did the experiment with using two 1 inch cube neodynium magnets. I used 1 magnet on the rotor and 1 magnet on the stator with radial flux alignment. The rotors are 18 cm in diameter with. The swivels don't use locks instead I put blockers inside the swivels to limit how they can rotate.

I put attachment points on the rim that I could hook a digital scale to to measure torque requirements.

I used the scale to measure the force needed for latteral separation.

- from 0-15 degrees the rim torque increased from 0 lbs to 8 lbs on the scale
- from 15-30 degrees the rim torque decreased from 8 lbs to -0.2 lbs
- from 30-180 degrees the tim torque returned from -0.1 lbs to 0 lbs.

I then used the digital scale to measure the rim torque in the other direction where the magnets maintain alignment:

- from 0-20 degrees the rim torque increased from 0 lbs to 5.6 lbs
- From 20-90 degrees the rim torque decreased from 5.6 lbs to 0.1 lbs.
- From 90-180 degrees my digital scale is not sensitive enough

So there is a small imballance due to the exploitation of the arrangment of magnets, but it's so small that it's not worth it. Better luck next time, there's not enough of a difference here to be worth scavenging. There is one, but it's super tiny.

If you would like to try a replication, feel free, you'll find what I did
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E4GQYUwdkygGeKzmO3RyOJTQwPnvkj2p/view?usp=sharing